# TV Vocal Reverb Reduction 

Tags: vocals, reverb, reduction, lapel, microphone

Live broadcast show the scenario, 3 presenters, all lapel mic'd up. The studio itself isnt the best and dryest room to begin with. There appears to be a bit of an echo issue with one of the presenters' voice.. Any advice tips or tricks you could suggest would be gratefully welcomed... eq techniques maybe ? ?

I try and mic them as close to their mouths as possible, and also tried to hide the mic behind  the lapel of the jacket too to stop the mic from picking up the reflecting sound from the room..

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you leaving all the mics open, or are you switching them on and off as needed?  If you need to leave more than one mic open at a time, try switching the phase or using a downward expander.

Answer (score 0):

Supposedly the state of the art of reverb suppression:

http://www.zynaptiq.com/unveil/

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using acoustic blankets in the recording space